# c# bindingsource and linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dataset, bindingsource

I have a bindingsource which has been filled out by

tableadapter.fill(DS, param1);

lets say that this bindingsource has :

```
char num
A     1
B     2
C     3
```

how do I get num value with given char 'A' using linq?

I could literate using 
foreach (DataRowView data in this.p_EM_Select_Event_TypeBindingSource)
but I would like to know how to do this in linq

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399401.aspx

cheers

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to specify what your data type is.

Since you did not, I will create one here as a placeholder:

```
public class Data1
{

    public Data1()
    {
        Character = String.Empty;
        Number = -1;
        Other = null;
    }

    public String Character { get; set; }

    public int Number { get; set; }

    public object Other { get; set; }

}
```

Now that you have a data type, we can assume that your BindingSource is populated with this type of data:

Somewhere in your code, you have to fill your BindingList:

```
p_EM_Select_Event_TypeBindingSource.DataSource = new List<Data1>();
```

Methods like below make nice wrappers for these types of tasks:

```
public int GetIndex(String value)
{
    var result = -1;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        var list = (IList<Data1>)p_EM_Select_Event_TypeBindingSource.List;
        if (list.Any(x => x.Character == value))
        {
            result = list.IndexOf(list.First(x => x.Character == value));
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public int GetNumber(String value)
{
    var result = -1;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        var item = list.IndexOf(list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Character == value));
        if (item != null)
        {
            result = item.Number;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

To set the BindingSource to your data item with given Character "A", you can call your method:

```
p_EM_Select_Event_TypeBindingSource.Position = GetIndex("A");
```

Or, to get the Number to your data item with the given Character, you can call the similar method:

```
var number = GetNumber("A");
```